# Unable to use include function a file in Codeigniter

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, wamp

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

> Message: include(../models/loginDao.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>
> Filename: controllers/LoginCon.php
>
> Line Number: 3

Backtrace:

> File: C:\wamp\www\xxx\CodeIgniter-3.0.0\application\controllers\LoginCon.php
>   Line: 3
>   Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\wamp\www\xxx\CodeIgniter-3.0.0\application\controllers\LoginCon.php
>   Line: 3
>   Function: include
>
> File: C:\wamp\www\xxx\CodeIgniter-3.0.0\index.php
>   Line: 292
>   Function: require_once

But file named loginDao.php existed, in that path specified.
Please help me out as I am new to CodeIgniter

Comment: Your controller name should only have one upper case letter same in models `Logincon.php` and `class Logincon extends CI_Controller {}` codeigniter 3 is case sensitive and same apples for models.

Comment: I think `../models/loginDao.php` indicates to PHP that the path you are looking for is: `C:\wamp\www\xxx\CodeIgniter-3.0.0\application\controllers\models\ `, however you may want to change the path to: `../../models/loginDao.php` so that it is looking in `C:\wamp\www\xxx\CodeIgniter-3.0.0\application\models\ `.

Comment: Can you post what the code looks like?

Comment: Try with `include APPPATH . 'models/loginDao';`. But before that you should read some [docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html) about hot to use models in CodeIgniter concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loading of codeigniter models & controllers, should only have first letter of class and file name upper case

**Controller**

[CodeIgniter User Guide Controllers](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html)

File name: Logincon.php

```
<?php 

class Logincon extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
       $this->load->model('logindao');
    }


    public function index() {
        $data['something'] = $this->logindao->get_somthing();

        $this->load->view('login', $data);
    }

}
```

**Model**

[CodeIgniter Userguide Models](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html)

File name: Logindao.php

```
<?php

class Logindao extends CI_Model {
    public function get_somthing() {
       // Some model code
    }
}
```

Your include method: I would not load models this way.

```
<?php

include APPPATH . 'models/Logindao.php';

// Or

include FCPATH . `application/models/Logindao.php`;
```